# Loading CSS returns 404 using django

Tags: python, html, css, django

I am building a chatbot application. The CSS for the frontend is not getting loaded by using django's static data load.

path to css is  - C:\Documents\Django_Workspace\bot\templates\static\bot.css

path to html is - C:\Documents\Django_Workspace\bot\templates\index.html

I have added STATIC_URL in my settings file as

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

The HTML link tag looks like

```
{% load static %}
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>bot</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "bot.css" %}" />
</head>
```

My Urls.py looks like

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

This is how I render the html page

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
from .models import User_Message

def index(request):
   template = loader.get_template('index.html')
   return HttpResponse(template.render())
```

Can anyone help. I've even tried hardcoding the path of css file in the html tag. But, that's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to run the following

python manage.py collectstatic

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS file shouldn't be in the `templates` folder but in a `static` folder within the `app`. From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files):

> Store your static files in a folder called static in your app. For example my_app/static/my_app/example.jpg.

See the rest of that section too, it's very succint. You probably want to have a `myapp` folder inside `static`, to avoid collisions if you have more apps.